# How to boot into internet recovery mode with rEFInd installed?

Tags: startup, recovery, dual-boot, efi

I have the bootup manager [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) installed on my Macbook. The key combinations for recovery (Command R and Command R+I) just boot into rEFnd's bootloader. At this point in time holding the option key while booting still allows me to plug in a USB and boot it (e.g. I can boot a Linux Live USB and wipe the disk - afterwards I'd be able to do internet recovery mode without a problem). That being said I'd like to be able to access internet recovery without the usage of external media and without giving up rEFInd. How can I achieve this?

Comment: purely for my own edification, how long do you press and hold the option key?

Comment: @Thufir I gave up and wiped the disk, reset NVRAM+SMC, and restored from internet recovery mode.

Comment: I think `c` will work.  But, it *seems* to be inconsistent..\

Answer (score 1):

I managed to start the internet recovery mode with rEFInd installed by holding right CMD + alt + R just after pressing power button and before rEFInd starts.