# how to boot a from a DVD?

Tags: keyboard, dual-boot, efi

On a friends older MacBook, I'm holding the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> key with a bootable DVD inserted but am not seeing a boot menu.  I've tried `rEFIt` as well as some Linux DVD's I have lying about.  I've checked the DVD's on another system and they are bootable on non-Mac hardware fine.

In [excruciating detail](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/325258/112208), what's the process for booting from a DVD for the Mac?  I've tried holding the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> key, tapping, holding until I see an Apple logo -- and everything in between.

*I've previously gotten this particular machine to boot live Linux DVD's.  As I recall, that was with the option key -- and, I don't recall having to hold and release at specific junctures.  It has since had a Mac OS 10.x clean install.
I installed Bodhi Linux, and then Lubuntu.  I don't recall jumping through any particular hoops, beyond, as best I recall, holding the `option` key until getting boot options.  It's like a firmware update, or perhaps newer OS, somehow made it harder to boot Linux or Linux type discs...?*

**As Allan suggests, the Genius Bar likely restored back to factory.  Which doesn't explain why `option` worked to boot to DVD before but doesn't anymore.**

Comment: See: [Ways to start up your Mac - Mac Help](https://help.apple.com/machelp/mac/10.12/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/mh26785) On start up, press and hold the C key immediately, while the screen is still black.

Comment: Which MacBook is it?  A white one, perhaps?

Comment: @Allan I'll update tonight with system info, pardon.  It's black. color matters?  Also, there's no symbol on the option key as I recall.  I think it says alt.

Comment: @creidhne just hold `c` until I get boot options?  Caps doesn't matter, presumably.  Weird, because, I remember using `option` before.  But, okay.

Comment: Black/white, same diff. If I remember correctly, the only DVD it will boot from is a macOS install DVD.  it won't boot Linux or Windows...

Comment: @Allan see, that's just it.  I installed Linux on this machine about a month ago.  He didn't like it then, but now wants dual boot.  Maybe the "Genius Bar" changed a setting or something????

Comment: Were you using rEFIt?  They may have wiped that partition and restored you back to factory

Answer (score 4):

Press and hold the `C` key on boot to attempt booting from the optical drive.

If that doesn't work I'd recommend trying the boot CD in another machine, and a different boot CD in the mac.

Comment: thx dude.  I'll try tonight.